Facebook Campaings to not be limited for iOS/Android apps
I'm implementing Facebook Core sdk to be able to run app facebook campaigns. I have a question about what should be added to an iOS and Android project so that campaigns are not limited in any way. I can see that i need to add to project manifest/info.plist the fb appid, fb client id and fb appname and in iOS on app delegate I need to call:
ApplicationDelegate.shared.application

Is there anything else that I need to call/configure for both iOS and Android since I can see some things mentioned in the documentation below:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios/ like: advertiser id collectable, auto log app events etc. Should those be added and why?
